# RFE module throws positional argument error

Tags: scikit-learn

all may I know whether the RFE module is working fine. It has been working well since yesterday but now it throws a positional argument error.

[image]

In both jupyter and google collab notebook. Any idea why so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am getting the same error on google colab notebook